# Rosinstall fails for openni drivers

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use Ubuntu 11.10 and I try to communicate to a Kinect sensor (the kinect is connected). I followed the instruction from http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect and get some problems.

```
cd openni && make
make[1]:Entering directory '/root/drivers/openni'
git clone https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI.git build/openni
Cloning into build/openni...
remote: Counting objects: 4866, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2064/2064), done.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly MiB | 1 kiB/s
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
make[1]: ***[build/openni] Error 128
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/drivers/openni'
make: *** [openni_lib] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35230/rosinstall-fails-for-openni-drivers/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That looks like GitHub had a hiccup or your network connection.  It should work when the issues is resolved.  And as @Mac says it's recommended to use the binary installs when possible.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd suggest installing them from binaries instead: `apt-get install ros-fuerte-openni-kinect`

Also, when you are building parts of ROS from source, you shouldn't do it as root.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-05-30**:
is this avaliable for debian - I'm getting an error unable to locate package? - Thanks M

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-05-31**:
For actually-Debian, not Ubuntu?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-05-31**:
Debian:squeeze specifically

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-06-01**:
So far as I know, .debs are only built for Ubuntu, so a source install is the way to go. I like @tfoote's idea that this is a github hiccup, and you should try again (see also: don't build ROS nodes as root).